# Toggle touchpad in HP ProBook 4530s

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I have a small problem. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my HP laptop and among some problems, I'm trying to solve a touchpad problem. It's working, but I can't toggle it on/off.

In Suse Linux Enterprise Desktop (which was preinstalled) and Windows, the touchpad could be enabled/disabled by touching the left upper corner. In Ubuntu I touched that area many times, but nothing happened.

I also tried to install SLED drivers from HP site using (first I converted the RPM package to a Debian package and then installed it, but that didn't fix the problem, I just have "Touchpad" in unity, when I'm typing "synaptics" but when I clicked - nothing happened.)

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your hardware, but were I to face a similar problem, I'd try the following:

To turn touchpad ON:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

To turn touchpad OFF:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```

Comment: Unfourtanately it doesn't work so good as in, for example, windows... "I don't have your hardware" I have HP ProBook 4530s, with Intel i3 processor, 4 GB RAM, internal intel hd video card + discrete radeon 6490M.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it from:

```
System setting > Mouse & Touchpad > set Touchpad on/off
```